# Use the C preprocessor to increment defines?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have an application which needs to define indexes in various .h files in a hierarchical manner. There is a large set of common entries in a single file and a number of variant header files that are pulled in to specific projects.

In file: "base.h"

```
   #define AAA 1
   #define BBB 2
   #define CCC 3
```

In many files like: "variant_extended.h"

```
   #define XXX 4
   #define YYY 5
   #define ZZZ 6
```

**However, this is cumbersome, is there a simple way to carry on from base.h and auto-number the defines in the build process?**

I am frequently editing the files to reorder or insert new entries which leads to a lot of manual management. I need to also, ensure the numbers start at 0 and are contiguous. These will be indexes in an array (like mailboxes).

Comment: Is there a really good reason you can't use an `enum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Jerry's comment:

```
// base.h
enum BaseCodes
{
   AAA = 1,
   BBB,
   CCC,
   FirstExtendedCode
};

// extended.h
enum ExtendedCodes
{
  XXX = FirstExtendedCode,
  YYY,
  ZZZ
}
```

In this case, ZZZ is guaranteed to be 6. Insert new members into the enums automatically renumbers all the other members.

Comment: So simple.. why didn't I think of that earlier. Doh!

Answer (score 2):

In base.h, add

```
#define BASE_LAST CCC
```

then in your variant_extended.h, use

```
#include "base.h"

#define XXX (BASE_LAST + 1)
#define YYY (BASE_LAST + 2)
#define ZZZ (BASE_LAST + 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove *some* of the pain by doing something like this:

```
   //
   // base.h
   //
   #define AAA 1
   #define BBB 2
   #define CCC 3
   #define LAST_BASE CCC
```

and:

```
   //
   // extended.h
   //

   #include "base.h"

   #define FIRST_EXTENDED (LAST_BASE + 1)
   #define XXX FIRST_EXTENDED
   #define YYY (FIRST_EXTENDED + 1)
   #define ZZZ (FIRST_EXTENDED + 2)
```

I suspect there's probably a better way if we had more information though.